# Adding up selected fields in drop down menus

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

Very new to coding and have created the below:

```
<option value="Select your magazine"> Select your magazine</option>
<option value="100 mag| 78.99"> 100 mag | 78.99</option>
<option value="250 mag | 136.99"> 250 mag| 136.99</option>
<option value="500 mag | 284.99"> 500 mag  | 284.99</option>
```

I wanted the person to select one option from this menu and another two options from the other menus similar to this.

I want to be able to get a total down the bottom of the page.

How do I go about doing this?

Secondly, how do I get the paypal button to work once they have selected the multi options from the drop down menus?

Lastly, how can I also add a coupon (discount) to their order with a secret word?

I have searched high and low and I'm a tad confused. HELP Needed :-).

Comment: For me its not clear what you exactly need. Do you need to optimize your dropdown (two dropdowns in one form), or do you need a paypal payment solution?

Comment: This question is not a great format for S.O. You're looking for suggestions rather than having a specific question. That being said, if you're using jquery then you'd listen to the `.change` event of your `select` tag and update the pricing total.

Comment: @CodyG.@Ronnie.Oosting - First I need to get my menus adding up to finalise the total of what the person has selected in the menus - example here: https://500views.com/youtube-views/
Then I need to add a paypal payment method to it. like the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be working exactly how you want it for one selected option. Look at it and try to figure out how to add more options. Good Luck!

```
<?php
$magazines = isset($_POST['magazine']) ? $_POST['magazine'] : 0;//returns the price 
//of the selected magazine

//add more select options here

$totalprice = 0;//initiate price variable
$discount = 0;//initiate discount variable

$price += $magazines;//Increment the price
$pricing['prices'] = ['78.99', '136.99', '284.99']; // set the prices
$pricing['selected'] = 'None';//use this to determine which one is selected

foreach($pricing['prices'] as $i){
    if($magazines === $i){//compare
        //set the selected price
        $pricing['selected'] = $i;
    }
}

$codeaccepted = 'ABC123';//accepted discount code
$codesubmitted=isset($_POST['discountcode'])? $_POST['discountcode'] : '';//submitted 
//code

if($codesubmitted == $codeaccepted){
    $discount = .20;//only set the discounts if the codes match
}
$discount = 1 - $discount;//math
$price = $price * $discount;//apply the discount
?>

<form method='post' action='stuff.php'>
<p>Select Your magazine</p>
<select name='magazine' id='magazine' onchange='updatePrice()'>
        <option value=0>Select</option>
    <?php foreach($pricing['prices'] as $i){
        if($i === $pricing['selected']){?>
            <!--display the selected option price-->
            <option selected value=<?php echo $i?> ><?php echo $i?></option><?php
        }else{?>
            <!--display all other prices-->
            <option value=<?php echo $i?> ><?php echo $i?></option><?php
        }
    }?>
</select>
<button type='submit' name='submit' id='button' style='display:none;'>Submit</button>
<input type='text' name='discountcode'>
<button type='submit' name='submit'>Use Code</button>
</form>

<p><?php echo $price?></p>

<script>
function updatePrice(){
    button = document.getElementById('button');
    button.click();//submit the form
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want exactly what you want with the menus but you need to encase your options in a select and in a form.

```
<form method='post' action='yourphpfile.php'>
<select name='variablename' id='variablename'>
     <option value="Select your magazine"> Select your magazine</option>
     <option value="100 mag| 78.99"> 100 mag | 78.99</option>
     <option value="250 mag | 136.99"> 250 mag| 136.99</option>
     <option value="500 mag | 284.99"> 500 mag  | 284.99</option>
</select>
<button type='submit' name='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

The name field will allow you to grab the content with php.
In terms of the discount code you can create a form by

```
<form method='post' action='yourphpfile.php'>
    <input type='text' name='discountcode'>
    <button type='submit' name='submit'>Use Code</button>
</form>
```

Then at the top in the php section use the 'discountcode' name to grab the input by, and set the code you want by.

```
$codeaccepted = 'ABC123';
$codesubmitted=isset($_POST['discountcode'])? $_POST['discountcode'] : '';
```

Then you can do a simple if statement if the codes are alike and set the discounts in the if statement.

Comment: So if I put the other 3 menus (options) in a select and in a form it will get a total once the user has selected their mags from each menu? So up the top in the pho section do you mean put that discount code there? Further, if statements - can you show me please? Thanks for your help it’s very helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the form/select code and it has a submit button  but what I want to do is something like this https://500views.com/youtube-views/. 
See how you can select a package and then at the end it totals it up and then you can pay via paypal?

Answer (score 0):

I put together something for you to start with. Its not perfect but take it and play around with it.

```
<?php
//this should give an array all the prices you marked
$magazines = isset($_POST['magazine']) ? $_POST['magazine'] : '';

$pricing = [78.99, 136.99, 284.99];
$totalprice = 0;
$discount = 0;
foreach($magazine as $i){
//loop over all the marked magazines and add the prices
    $price += $i;
}
$codeaccepted = 'ABC123';
$codesubmitted=isset($_POST['discountcode'])? $_POST['discountcode'] : '';

if($codesubmitted == $codeaccepted){
    $discount = .20;//only set the discounts if the codes match
}
$discount = 1 - $discount;
$price = $price * $discount;//apply the discount
?>

<form method='post' action='yourphpfile.php'>
    <p>Select Your magazine</p>
    <select name='variablename' id='variablename' onchange='updatePrice()'>
        <?php foreach($pricing as $i){?>
            <option value= <?php echo $i?> ><?php echo $i?></option><?php
        }?>
    </select>
    <button type='submit' name='submit' id='button' 
           style='display:none;'>Submit</button>
</form>

<form method='post' action='yourphpfile.php'>
    <input type='text' name='discountcode'>
    <button type='submit' name='submit'>Use Code</button>
</form>

<script>
    function updatePrice(){
        button = document.getElementById('button');
        button.click();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Try this. I added a javascript function that calls that form button when a select option is changed. Then on the select option I added a onchange attribute that called the javascript function. Finally I made the button hidden to clean up the look of the page.